# How to remove element saving it's content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example:

```
<div id="block">
    <div id="wrapper">
        Some content
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        Little more
    </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to remove `#wrapper` saving it's content. All jQuery data and events of `#wrapper` content must be saved. The content of `#wrapper` is unknown so neither `$( '#wrapper p' ).unwrap()` nor `$( '#block' )[ 0 ].innerHTML += $( '#wrapper' ).html; $( '#wrapper' ).remove;` are not acceptable.

Result must be:

```
<div id="block">
    Some content
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    Little more
</div>
```

Comment: Answers on "duplicated" question don't solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $wrapper = $( '#wrapper' );
    $contents = $wrapper.contents();

if ( $contents.length )
    $contents.first().unwrap();
else
    $wrapper.remove();
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)